# print output to stderr in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

I would like to capture both stdout and stderr from org-mode code block to output.

```
#+begin_src python :results output
import sys
print("hello stdout", file=sys.stdout)
print("hello stderr", file=sys.stderr)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: hello stdout
```

Current sample only captured stdout text, how can I capture both?

Comment: Does [this](https://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2014/12/21/Capturing-stderr-from-Python-in-org-mode-take-2/) help?

Comment: here are som elinks on this topic that might help you: https://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2015/01/04/Redirecting-stderr-in-org-mode-shell-blocks/
https://necromuralist.github.io/posts/org-babel-stderr-results/
https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/48835/help-me-avoid-true-in-org-babel-bash-statements